# Button text coming in two lines and increasing the length of lightning button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-button

i have a lightning component button which has a longer text and it is going in two seperate lines and forming the following structure. Is there any way to keep it in a single line?
[image]

i used the following piece of code for the buttons

Comment: Can you add code for the markup not just for the button, the sizing div it is surrounded by, Think its because of that

Comment: yes please add your code